# How to make an app for a website?

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, mobile, blogs

I'm planning on making an app that can access posts from a WordPress blog and display them. I would start with iOS but I could use cross-platform frameworks too. I'm looking for something more programming-oriented instead of a drag and drop interface so that I can have extensive options for further development. What is the best code-based way to display blog posts from a WordPress site? I'm aiming towards something similar to the CNET app. Does anyone know how they made theirs?

Comment: Dude this question has a shelf life of 10 minutes

Comment: @DrewPierce I'm just asking for the optimal way to make an app for a WordPress blog

Comment: Maybe start with a shell to get it up to speed fast. http://codecanyon.net/item/ionfullapp-ionic-phonegapcordova-full-hybrid-app/10400343

Comment: The easiest way to get data from wordpress is by activating the jetpack api and then accessing it with: https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects/blob/master/AlamofireJsonToObjectsTests/WordpressTest.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just install a theme that is responsive, so that it's mobile friendly. By the way you asked the question, this sounds pretty ambitious. However, if you want to get your feet wet, consider looking into PhoneGap / Cordova perhaps.